# Getting an image from Url in Android

Tags: java, android, sql

I am trying to get an image from a url stored in a table but when I try to get the image the ImageView doesn't contain anything it is just blank.

In my code below I have used Picasso to get the picture:

```
public class Imageoffam extends AppCompatActivity {
private boolean success = false; // boolean
private ConnectionClass connectionClass;
public TextView tmtmt;
public ImageView dede;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imageoffam);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    tmtmt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tomato) ;
    dede = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dededede);
    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();

    SyncData orderData = new SyncData();
    orderData.execute("");
}

private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String msg = "Success";
    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(Imageoffam.this, "Synchronising",
                "Please Wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            Connection conn = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (conn == null) {
                msg = "Please Check Your Connection";
                success = false;
            } else {

                String dta = getIntent().getStringExtra("blala");
                String query = "SELECT Images.Fimage,family.FName,family.FInfo,family.CID FROM Images INNER JOIN family ON family.FID = Images.FID WHERE family.FInfo = (N'" +dta+ "')";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    try { 
                        Picasso.with(Imageoffam.this).load(rs.getString("Fimage")).into(dede);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
            msg = writer.toString();
            success = false;

        }
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        progress.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(Imageoffam.this, msg + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (success == false) {
        } else {
            try {

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't give any error message although it doesn't show the image in the ImageView.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you store image uri in db you need to setting uri on ImageView by
imageView.setImageUri(uri);
after get to uri from db

Comment: sorry i can't undrstand you,where do i put  imageView.setImageUri(uri);

Comment: you use Picasso so you can get uri and passed directly in Picasso
                        Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(dede);

Answer (score 0):

When using Picasso, no need of AsyncTask, just do:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUri).into(ivBasicImage);
```

For example:

```
String imageUri = "https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg";
ImageView ivBasicImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBasicImage);
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUri).into(ivBasicImage);
```

You can also try [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/):

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Great,but whats a fragment?

Comment: Just remove it from the code and remove the code where you are calling it.

Comment: i cant remove it when i do so it gives me errors,First error is on orderData.execute("");,second error is in the @overide,what do i do?

Comment: Remove the SyncData class and last 2 lines of onCreate() function

Comment: but when i do so nothing happens!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of the picasso method,
I recommend the local webview method.